# Comments Replying UX/UI

Tags: user-interface, recursion, comments, user-experience, reply

So I am developing a forum in which I can have comments being replyied over comments. This can go forever in many levels of replying using a recursive algorythm. 
I want to avoid the classic reply ui experience where the replying comment is nested inside the other comment. I want to avoid diplaying comments this way.
Any good ideas out there to solve this problem?

Comment: Keep a  maximum nesting threshold and when new replies are made which exceed this limit show them one below another instead of nesting.
**This is not the right place for this question** . Post your question in http://ux.stackexchange.com

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks. Posting there.